# Java 8 how to handle a case when the attribute is null

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have one void method that does something on the object passed as a param

```
public void someMethod(Object object) {
...
}
```

and I want to invoke it in other method - but only when the one of the Object attributes is not null.

```
public void otherMethod(Number number) {
 repository.findObject(number)
.filter(o -> o.getAttributeOne().isPresent())
.ifPresent(o -> performThirdMethod(o));
}
```

I want to make sure that performThirdMethod() will be only invoked when one of the object attribute (attributeOne) is NOT null. 
Is above method correct? I also wonder what would be the best way to test if this actually works?

In other words - how (in Java8) I can filter the result to see if the attribute is present - if in one method I am passing a whole object and want to check only one attribute presence that belongs to it?

Comment: What isn't working in the example code you provided?  You should provide a more complete example as we don't know for sure what the return types of methods like o.getAttributeOne() are.  Can this return null or is it always returning a non-null Optional that wraps the attribute?

Comment: How is `someMethod` relevant at all?

Comment: What does `findObject` and `filter` return respectively?

Comment: You seem to be most likely looking for `repository.findObject(number).filter(o -> o.getAttributeOne() != null).ifPresent(o -> performThirdMethod(o));`

Comment: Sorry for that - attributeOne is nullable. FindObject will return a whole Object. filter will return boolean if the attribute is present (true) .

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadoc of [`Optional.ifPresent(Consumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer))

> If a value is present, performs the given action with the value, **otherwise does nothing.**

Since it's a lambda `o -> performThirdMethod(o)`, not a direct invocation of `performThirdMethod`, you are given a guarantee that the method "will be only invoked when one of the object attribute (`attributeOne`) is NOT null".

> I also wonder what would be the best way to test if this actually works?

I use a debugger with a breakpoint inside a lambda. You also can log a message before calling `performThirdMethod`.

```
.ifPresent(o -> {
    System.out.println("performThirdMethod will be executed");
    performThirdMethod(o);
});
```

Since Java 9, there is `ifPresentOrElse(Consumer,Runnable)` to perform a empty-based action if no value is present.

```
.ifPresentOrElse(
    o -> performThirdMethod(o),
    () -> System.out.println("performThirdMethod won't be executed")
);
```

Comment: Thank You! But by lambda  o -> performThirdMethod(o) - wouldn't I only check if the whole Object exists? Not this particular atrribute I will need to perform ThirdMethod ?